# How to bind property (checked) from checkbox in dialog with label on the column table, SAPui5

Tags: javascript, binding, dialog, sapui5

i have a view, which contains table; with onclick event dialog pops up with checkboxes in it. When user checkes boxes, the same columns(as checkboxes) should be added to the table. How to bind properties of checkbox (checked: true) with column(setVisible) ?
Thank you!

ex of checkbox:

```
var tv3 = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text : 'Equipment Tag',
    checked: false,
});
```

one of the tablecolumn

```
table.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        text : "Functional Location"
    })
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking how to bind checkbox selections in a dialog with visibility of columns in a table. You can use a JSON model to achieve this:

- have visibility properties for each of the columns you want bind
- those model properties to the visible property of each column control
- bind those model properties also to the checkbox control's selected
  property

The two-way binding will mean that the effect is achieved. I've written a [working example with a JSON model, commons Table, Columns and CheckBox controls in a Dialog](https://gist.github.com/qmacro/8800041) for you to see.

Here are the salient parts:

Visibility in JSON model:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    visibleColumns: {
        firstName: true,
        lastName: true
    },
    names: [
        { firstName: "DJ", lastName: "Adams" },
        { firstName: "Joseph", lastName: "Adams" }
    ] 
}));
```

Visibility binding on Column:

```
new sap.ui.table.Column({
    visible: "{/visibleColumns/firstName}",
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "First Name" }),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: "{firstName}" })
}),
```

Visibility binding on CheckBox:

```
new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text: "First Name",
    checked: "{/visibleColumns/firstName}"
})
```

Bonus: You may be interested in the TablePerso* mechanism set in the [sap.m](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.html) library which does a similar thing for column visibility.

Comment: Dear Qmarco, thank you so much for taking your time! :) i am a very beginner, so good tips are very welcome! :)

Comment: upps Sorry qmacro...answered without glasses haahha :)

Comment: Hello! qmacro, I have Q - if you have time. The TO has changes, so functionality is different. at the moment i have the dialog, which contains 2 listBoxes. user point/shoot the List items from one list box to another. so another list - are the columns of the table. what is the best approach in this case? i thought maybe compare 2 arrays(initial on the left and what we got in the right), then via loop add the columns? not sure though. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You might want to re-phrase this question to be (a) more specific and (b) as a question rather than a comment.

Comment: sure! what i supposed to build is:  a table with 91 columns(only few are visible initially). user can choose which columns he wants to have by opening dialog. in a  dialog there are have 2 listboxes and 2 buttons (add, remove, save). first listbox has list items(91). second is initially empty. user can move list items from 1 to anohter and back. when user press on "save", the items from filled second list becomes a columns in the table. i hope it is more clear. thank you

Comment: No, I mean a new specific question, not a new comment. See the placeholder text in the new comment box before you type :-) or see http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46826/discussion-between-user3189516-and-qmacro)